# Wordpress site doesn't work on Internet Explorer

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer, css, media-queries

I'm building a theme for Wordpress, but it seens to not work on Internet Explorer, especialy above IE 9.

Here is the site: http://icomeg.com.br/

It looks like the background image doens't resize automaticaly or something (I'm using CSS3 Media Queries), my site froze completly, I did a research and tried to put this filter:

```
.centered_header{ /*criação das caixas do header */
position: relative;

height: 130px;
margin: 0 auto;

background-image: url(../ico-theme/images/header-ok21.jpg);
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;

filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader( src='../ico-theme/images/header-ok21.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader( src='../ico-theme/images/header-ok21.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";}
```

On Chrome and Firefox works well but in IE it's a completly mess, is someone can help me?

Comment: could you possibly add a link / jsfiddle?

Comment: Here: http://icomeg.com.br/

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works fine for me.

```
.centered_header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background: url(../ico-theme/images/header-ok21.jpg);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```